# Magento 1.9 Get Actual category of current product

Tags: magento-1.9

Categories:

```
--Women (isAnchor = Yes)
    -- Clothing (isAnchor = Yes)
        --T-Shirt (isAnchor = Yes)
```

Products:

```
Simple product, Category assigned (T-Shirt)
```

When Product is visited from T-Shirt category then you get correct category name.

When product is viewed from Category Women or Clothing then you get current category but not T-Shirt

```
it returns Registry('CURRENT_CATEGORY')
```

I want to get the category that is actually assigned to the product.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

setting isAnchor property to 'Yes' for T-shirt as well might resolve the issue

Comment: I have tried changing isAnchor Property to 'Yes' for T-Shirt, Still no luck.